# C - reading file and splitting with strtok into an array

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, strtok

So I'm trying to read a file which is a series of words and sentences split up by `|` and separate them with `strtok()` while putting the tokens into an array. Then print the array just to check if the contents are correct.
However, the output comes out incorrectly.
Here's my code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char *str=malloc(80*sizeof(char));
    int count=0;
    char *tokenArray[100];
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    char *token = strtok(str, "|");

    printf("Loading stock...\n");
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    while(fgets(str, sizeof(str),fp)!=NULL){        
        tokenArray[0]=strtok(str,"|");

        for(i=1; i<200; i++){
            if((tokenArray[i]=strtok(NULL,"|")) ==NULL)
                break;
        }
        count=i;

        for(i=0; i<count;i++){
            printf("%d: %s\n",i,tokenArray[i]);
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Which results with the output:

```
Loading stock...
0: I0001
1: M
0: eat Pie
0: Yummy
0: Beef in
0:  Gravy
0: surroun
0: ded by
0: pastry
0: 3.50
1: 50
0:

0: I0002
1: A
0: pple Pi
0: e
1: Delic
0: ious St
0: ewed Ap
0: ple in
0: a Yummy
0:  Pastry
0:  envelo
0: pe
1: 3.00
0: 20
```

Which is not great.
However if I tweak it so str is static `char str[80];` it works out and the output is

```
0: I0001
1: Meat Pie
2: Yummy Beef in Gravy surrounded by pastry
3: 3.50
4: 50
```

But for the sake of my assignment, I must be using `malloc()`. 
What is going wrong?

Comment: The first `char *token = strtok(str, "|");` is before `str` has any data.

Comment: This: 'for(i=1; i<200; i++)' is also worrying, since array indices start at 0, and the max valid index for 'tokenArray' is 99.

Comment: As you read in each line, you overwrite the previous line. So the pointers you have stored no longer point to the tokens you imagine. You must allocate memory for and copy each token.

Answer (score 1):

Please see fixed version of your code with comments inline. Your main problem was incorrect interpretation of `sizeof(str)` (and that, in fact, explains why it worked when `str` was an array of characters instead of a pointer), but I also fixed some of the issues mentioned in comments on the original question. Also, you might want to investigate how `strtok()` actually works if you have multiple lines that need tokenizing - as mentioned by Weather Vane, as-is it will not work with multiple lines if you want to keep the old tokens. I will leave the proper fix for that issue as an exercise for the OP if that's what the assignment is asking for.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 80

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char *str=malloc(BUF_SIZE*sizeof(char));
    int count=0;
    char *tokenArray[100];
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    // See comment by Weather Vane
    //char *token = strtok(str, "|");
    char *token;

    printf("Loading stock...\n");
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    // sizeof(str) == sizeof(char *) == 8 on x86_64, NOT 80 as you assumed
    //while(fgets(str, sizeof(str),fp)!=NULL){
    while(fgets(str, BUF_SIZE, fp)!=NULL){

        tokenArray[0]=strtok(str,"|");

        // See comment by Martin James about array bounds
        //for(i=1; i<200; i++){
        for(i=1; i < sizeof(tokenArray)/sizeof(tokenArray[0]); i++){
            if((tokenArray[i]=strtok(NULL,"|")) ==NULL)
                break;
        }
        count=i;

        for(i=0; i<count;i++){
            printf("%d: %s\n",i,tokenArray[i]);
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Works fine if `test.txt` contains:

```
I0001|Meat Pie|Yummy Beef in Gravy surrounded by pastry|3.50|50
```

And is called as:

```
$./tmp test.txt
```

Output:

```
Loading stock...
0: I0001
1: Meat Pie
2: Yummy Beef in Gravy surrounded by pastry
3: 3.50
4: 50
```